# Passing sql statements as strings to mssql with C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

This is a really, really stupid question but I am so accustomed to using linq / other methods for connecting and querying a database that I never stopped to learn how to do it from the ground up.

Question: How do I establish a manual connection to a database and pass it a string param in C#? (yes, I know.. pure ignorance).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", fileID);

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr =
                   cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                // process row from resultset;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One uses the [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class to execute commands (either stored procedures or sql) on SQL Server using ado.net.  Tutorials abound.

Comment: Thanks - I attempted to search for it but was getting a wide range of results, none of which seemed to be what I was looking for. the SqlCommand class certainly narrows down my search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx

```
public void RunStoredProcParams()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataReader rdr  = null;

        // typically obtained from user
        // input, but we take a short cut
        string custId = "FURIB";

        Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer Order History:\n");

        try
        {
            // create and open a connection object
            conn = new 
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            // 1.  create a command object identifying
            //     the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(
                "CustOrderHist", conn);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows
            //    to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameter to command, which
            //    will be passed to the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

            // execute the command
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // iterate through results, printing each to console
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Product: {0,-35} Total: {1,2}",
                    rdr["ProductName"],
                    rdr["Total"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: An improvement to this example is to use the "using" keyword to automatically dispose of Connection, Command and Reader instances.

Comment: Also: setting explicit data types for the query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

3 things no one else has shown you yet:

- "Stacking" using statements
- Setting an explicit parameter type rather than letting .Net try to pick one for you
- "var" keyword

.

```
string sql = "MyProcedureName";

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        .Value = "MyParameterValue";

    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader rdr =
               cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            // process row from resultset;
        }
    }
}
```